# How to get my rails pages to return as html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've written a rails site in the latest version of rails, based on knowledge of rails from a couple of years ago, and I've hit a horrible snag.

I foolishly decided to ignore the new RESTful routing system and hope for the best.

So all of my views are plain .erb, NOT html.erb

my routes file looks like this

```
map.connect '/crm/:action/:id', :controller => "contacts", :format => 'html'
```

here is an example of a method:

```
def update_emails
  Com.update_emails
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to(:action => 'list')}
  end
end
```

when it redirects to the 'list' action, I get a plain text file that my browser tries to download, instead of the html version of the page that I want.

Is there a simple way for me to tell rails to only send html format files?

Thank you!

EDIT:

list action

```
def list
  if params[:search]
    @contacts = Contact.search(params)
  else
    @contacts = Contact.find(:all, :order => "updated_at desc")
  end
end
```

and the view is a plain .erb file (problem is the same when I make it a .html.erb file)

Also, the same thing happens when I redirect_to other actions

Comment: Please post one of the methods in your controllers (e.g., index or edit)

Comment: Also, are your views "*.html.erb"?

Comment: I've edited the post to answer your questions

Comment: just tried changing list.erb to list.html.erb, same issue :(

Comment: What does the "list" action look like?

Comment: def list
    if params[:search]
      @contacts = Contact.search(params)
    else
      @contacts = Contact.find(:all, :order => "updated_at desc")
    end
  end

Comment: added the list action to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You should use respond_to.

```
def update_emails
  Com.update_emails
  redirect_to(:action => 'list')
end
```

and then in the 'list' action

```
def list
  #some code here
  respond_to |format| do
    format.html {render :list}
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried that (except 'redirect_to', not 'render'), and get the same issue.

Comment: That's not the same thing.I've edit my response.see if this works.

Comment: Close! Thank you! You put me on the right track. Couple of adjustments. redirect_to(:action => 'list', :format => 'html')            and               respond_to do |format|                                                 and                             format.html {render(:action => 'list')}          And it works!!!